# TeXMaker and El Capitan

Tags: texmaker, mac

My TeXMaker (version 4.5) is not able to compile after my recent update to El Capitan. I have followed the hints suggested online, changed all paths containing "/usr/texbin/..." to "/Library/TeX/texbin/..." but it still won't work. I get the message *"Konnte den Befehl nicht starten."/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"* which means "Couldn't execute command [...]". A screenshot of my settings can be seen below. I'd be very grateful for help. [image: Settings]

Comment: Run `which pdflatex` in the Terminal. What does it tell you?

Comment: It doesn't tell me anything..

Comment: Which version of MacTeX have you installed ? Does `/Library/TeX/texbin` actually exist ?

Comment: That is a good question. I am about to install the newest version now - maybe that fixes the problem.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments below the question